React JS. Утечка памяти при перезагрузке страницы?
Учусь разрабатывать веб приложения на React JS. 
Столкнулся с проблемой, что при нескольких перезагрузках страницы, используемое количество памяти вкладкой увеличивается.
Сделал снапшоты при 1 перезагрузке страницы, 5,10 и 20 перезагрузок. Вот что из этого вышло:

Куда копать, что бы найти причины этого?

Вы что то сохраняете в localStorage? Вообще такого быть не должно при перезагрузке страницы. При перезагрузке, старое удаляется и появляется новое. Рост памяти от перезапуска может быть вызван каким то подтягиванием большого количества данных(может вы в коде как то считает количество входов и от этого массив данных наполняете...)

Если вы используете Vite, нужно чистить кеш, сталкивался с проблемой на разных компьютерах
package.json
{
  "name": "real-estate-crm",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "cleanup": "npx -y rimraf ./node_modules/.vite",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}


cmd
npm run cleanup

